# How to see table relationships in database diagrams?

Tags: sql-server, ax

I have lots of tables and I know there are relationships between them because I can see some of them from Microsoft AX AOT. When I go to SQL server management studio and use database diagrams option I can add the tables I want but I cant see relationships? How can I see them?

Comment: If no relationships show up in the diagram, they probably don't exist. You may for example have an id in a table that relates to another table, but there may not be a foreign key relationship to actually join them, meaning a relationship is implied but doesn't actually exists. Check to see if table keys exist

Comment: Tanner is correct here. If they do not appear in the diagram they do not exist as foreign keys in the database. Try this query. select * from sys.foreign_keys. This is a start but could be expanded considerably based on what you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in table diagrams, and you have both AX 2012 and Visio installed, you can go to AX → Tools → Reverse engineer → Visio UML data model.

Or just right-click an AX project with tables → Add-Ins → Reverse engineer.

More info online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa499193.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Management Studio 2008 :

Expand the root Database, try and expand the Database Diagrams folder, it should say something like "no diagrams".

If it asks you to create a diagram say yes, then add the tables.

If not, right on Database Diagrams folder and create new Diagram.

Comment: Yes I have done that already and added tables I wanted to the diagram. But I dont see relationships between them.